# Regex Replace Multiple items

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace

Is it possible to replace multiple chars with multiple options? `a` replaced with `1` and so on

```
Private Sub Foo()
    Dim example As String = "+a+b+c+d+e"
    ' a = 1
    ' b = 2
    ' c = 3
    ' d = 4
    ' e = 5
    MessageBox.Show(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(example, "(a|b|c|d|e)", "stuck here"))
End Sub
```

The only way i can think of is with multiple expressions.

Answer (score 0):

With regular expression , I think it will be tough. However, you can use String.Replace and a loop to solve your problem.

**Pseudo-code**

```
map := {
    {'a', '1'},
    {'b', '2'},
    {'c', '3'},
    {'d', '4'},
    {'e', '5'}
}

s := '+a+b+c+d+e'

For i:=0 To s.length()
  If map.contains(s[i]) Then
     s[i] := map.getValue(s[i])
  End If
End For
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the post. I am practicing regular expressions so whats hoping for a regex way. I can use net methods easily. But thank you.